# Cambiar un valor de una fila concreta de mi bd

Tags: php, sql

Estoy intentando acceder a la tabla de mi bd, para cambiar un valor "revision" (ahora vale 1 y quiero pase a 2) de una fila concreta empleando su id.

Aunque el error me da a la hora de finalizar la conexión, yo creo que estoy haciendo mal la consulta, pero no se como hacerlo para acceder a esa fila y cambiar el valor de una de las celdas si no es de esta manera.

Me da el siguiente error:

*Warning: mysqli_free_result() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP_WEB_MMR\Plataforma\PHP\Proyecto\validarPropuesta.php on line 34*

```
<?php

// Conectamos con la base de datos.
$bd_host = "localhost"; 
$bd_usuario = "root"; 
$bd_password = ""; 
$bd_base = "carrot";


$conexion = mysqli_connect($bd_host, $bd_usuario, $bd_password); 
mysqli_select_db($conexion,$bd_base);

$idValidacion = $_POST['idValidar'];
//    $idValidacion = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['idValidar']);

$revision = 2;

$consulta = "
    INSERT INTO propuesta(revision)
    VALUES ('$revision')
    WHERE id = $idValidacion
";

$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

// Liberamos y cerramos conexión.
mysqli_free_result($resultado);
mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

Comment: Por favor, por favor, los mensajes de error se ponen como texto. Más en casos como este, que la imagen queda en un tamaño diminuto. Seleccionar, copiar y pegar los mensajes, por favor! :)

Comment: Una buena práctica es comprobar que la conexión a la BD se hace correctamente, para eso puedes poner `mysqli_connect($bd_host, $bd_usuario, $bd_password) or die("No se pudo conectar");`

Comment: @Alfabravo Editado, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

`INSERT INTO` es para insertar un nuevo registro, si lo que quieres  es actualizar un registro existente, debe utilizar `UPDATE`, la estructura según la documentación de MySQL es:

```
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_reference
    SET assignment_list
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [ORDER BY ...]
    [LIMIT row_count]

value:
    {expr | DEFAULT}

assignment:
    col_name = value

assignment_list:
    assignment [, assignment] ...
```

Para tu caso concreto, la consulta quedaría algo así:

```
UPDATE propuesta SET revision='$revision' WHERE id = $idValidacion
```

En cualquier caso indicar que concatenar valores en consultas es un muy mala práctica ya que da pie a inyección sql, en su lugar se debería usar sentencias preparadas.

---

Obviamente la consulta que tienes da error ya que no es valida, pues la sintaxis de `INSERT` no admite la cláusula `WHERE`. para evitar este tipo de errores puedes envolver `mysqli_query()` dentro de in if para determinar si la consulta se ejecuto con éxito, ejemplo:

```
if(!$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta)) {
    echo 'La consulta falló, error:'.mysqli_error($conexion);
}
```